# POST using CURL in PHP gives invalid request Error

Tags: php, post, curl, oauth, google-api

I am using below post method for google account using curl but it gives me invalid_request error.

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/ux5gNj-_mIu4DOD_gNZdjX9EtOFf&
client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=CENSORED&
redirect_uri=http://localhost/oauth2callback&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Here is my PHP code with curl

```
$text ='test';

$URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

$header = array(
"POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1",
"Host: accounts.google.com",
"Content-type: application/atom+xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
"Accept: text/xml",
"Cache-Control: no-cache", 
"code=[my_code]&client_id=[my_client_id]&client_secret=[my_client_secret]& redirect_uri=http://localhost/curl_resp.php&grant_type=authorization_code",
"Content-length: ".strlen($text),
);


 $xml_do = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($xml_do, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
 curl_setopt($xml_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
 curl_setopt($xml_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
 curl_setopt($xml_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($xml_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($xml_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
 curl_setopt($xml_do, CURLOPT_POST, false);
 curl_setopt($xml_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $text);
 curl_setopt($xml_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

And I am having invalid request error

Comment: Are those new lines following the `&` characters in the POST body there in the data you are sending to the server? Because they shouldn't be...

Comment: That PHP code does not seem complete, not to say that it is hardly readable. Edit your question and add your PHP there as a code block.

Comment: I added the `oauth` and `google-authentication` tags. It looks to me like this problem is not specifically with PHP, the POST method, or cURL. It looks to me like the request is reaching their server with no problem, but is being rejected by their server for some reason. I found a similar post that might help you: http://groups.google.com/group/HealthGraph/browse_thread/thread/bef64abe4ed2e92c?pli=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know anything about using Google's oAuth API, but from the examples that I have looked at so far, it looks like you are supposed to pass the values (i.e. `code`, `client_id`, etc.) in the post fields, not directly in the HTTP header.

The following example still doesn't work completely, but instead of getting a `invalid_request` error, it gives you `invalid_grant`. I think there is something else wrong in addition to what I've mentioned (perhaps you need new credentials from Google or something), but this might get you one step closer, at least:

```
$post = array(
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code", 
    "code" => "your_code", 
    "client_id" => "your_client_id", 
    "client_secret" => "your_client_secret", 
    "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost/curl_resp.php"
);

$postText = http_build_query($post);

$url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postText); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);    // gets an error, "invalid_grant"
```

Comment: just to clarify, usually "invalid_grant" is because the code: your_code is expired, revoked or already used for granting an access_token (you can use it once) ;)

Comment: This answer is very useful but I have  question how to revoke Auth code or get a new one?

Comment: @Yasser: Check [the manual](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) or ask a new question, if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The response to your request actually includes a very readable description of the problem:

> POST requests require a `Content-length` header.

Comment: $text ='test';

$URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

 $header = array(
 "POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1",
 "Host: accounts.google.com",
 "Content-type: application/atom+xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
 "Accept: text/xml",
 "Cache-Control: no-cache", 
 "code=[my_code]&client_id=[my_client_id]&client_secret=[my_client_secret]&redirect_uri=http://localhost/curl_resp.php&grant_type=authorization_code",
 "Content-length: ".strlen($text),
  );

Comment: I have used Google api php client library for getting access token and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have CURLOPT_POST set to **false**?

```
 curl_setopt($xml_do, CURLOPT_POST, false);
```

Although some configurations of cURL will automatically change this to tru if CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is set, you do not have a valid postfield.

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP 5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix.

It should either be in param=value syntax or an array passed.

Answer (score 0):

I have used post array in CURL method and valid Google code and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem, where google returns an "invalid_xxx".

After much researching and troubleshooting, the problem lies with the encoding of the form itself! Do not use function 'http_builder_query', as it messses up the string and google cannot 'recognise' it. Example :

http_builder_query Output : **"code=4%252FYYUT71KJ6..."**

compared to

just a normal string      : **"code=4/YYUT71KJ6..."**

Here is my working code, where i have placed 'x' in the locations that needs your own data (taken and modified from [google oauth authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629540/google-oauth-authentication))

```
    $code_from_user_login = "4/YYUT71KJ6....";
    $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);


        $post_params = "code=" . $code_from_user_login . "&";
        $post_params .= "redirect_uri=http://www.x.com/&";
        $post_params .= "client_id=x.apps.googleusercontent.com&";
        $post_params .= "client_secret=x&";
        $post_params .= "grant_type=authorization_code&";


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        print($result);
```

The result will be like :

```
  '{
  "access_token" : "ya29.AHES6ZSwJSHpTZ1t....",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3599,
  "id_token" : "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjU0MDQxOTZlMmQzOGNjYTA2MW...."
}'
```

Once you have the 'access_token', access the profile data with this url :
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE

~ end ~