# google OAUTH2 exchange authorization code for acces token "invalid request"

Tags: php, google-api, authorization, access-token

I'm getting google api authorization code from this page on my server

```
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/user-example.php
```

the same page on my hosting to test

```
http://mawk3y.net/google/google-api-php-client/examples/user-example.php
```

after adjusting client id, secret and redirect uri.

```
$data =file_get_contents('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?code='.$code.'&client_secret={secret}&redirect_uri={my web page}&grant_type=authorization_code');
print_r($data);
```

but i get an error so i'm trying to paste the full url to the browser address bar after getting authorization code from that page like this (the same auth code I get from this page https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code={authorization code}&redirect_uri=mywebpage.php&client_id={my client id}&client_secret={secret code}&grant_type=authorization_code
```

but the result is

```
{
"error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

how to solve this and exchange the authorization code for access token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the parameters in a *GET* request to the *authorization* endpoint (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth), but you must send them in a *POST* request to the *token* endpoint (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token).

Comment: It's the same uri all data are copied from the API console to avoid mistakes [UPDATE] added the test url on my hosting in the question

Comment: changed the answer after closer inspection of your params/URLs

Comment: inside document ready
$.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code={code}&client_secret={secret}&redirect_uri={uri}&grant_type=authorization_code').done(function(data){
 console.log(data);
 }).fail(function(){
 console.log('failed');
 });
the result is "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code={code}&client_secret={secret}&redirect_uri={redirect uri}&grant_type=authorization_code. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. token
"failed"

Comment: where does the javascript come from? you should handle the token request in PHP as suggested in the original question, e.g. using CURL as described in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932443/post-using-curl-in-php-gives-invalid-request-error

Comment: followed the answer and got  string(72) "{ "error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "Invalid code." }"  though this is the authorization code I get from google it's even the same code I got from https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and as I see it's because it's been expired or used so how can I get a new authorization code

Comment: You can't reuse old `code`'s; you must generate a fresh one for your client at the authorization endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Hanz for your help it's just my last question how can I get a new authorization code? every time I authenticate I get the same code

Comment: read this: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl